# Why I'm getting "Inconsistent accessibility: property type xxx..."?

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this?:

```
public abstract class EFNLBaseRepository:IDisposable
{

    NLSubscriberDBContext _dbContext;
    protected internal NLSubscriberDBContext dbContext
    {
     get
      {...}

    }
...
}


internal class NLSubscriberDBContext : DbContext
{
  ...
}
```

Of course, both classes are on the same assembly.
This is the compilation error I'm getting:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type
>   'NLSubscriber.Core.Service.Repository.EFDAL.NLSubscriberDBContext' is
>   less accessible than property
>   'NLSubscriber.Core.Service.Repository.EFDAL.EFNLBaseRepository.dbContext' C:\Data\Projects\Neticon\TFS\NLSubscriber
>   - Newsletter\NLSubscriber-newsletter\NLSubscriber.Core\Service\Repository\EFDAL\EFNLBaseRepository.cs 12  50  NLSubscriber.Core

Comment: now if you inherited EFNLBaseRepository in another assembly (perfectly legal) how would you from that assembly access its own property which is internal only to the assembly of the abstract class? make the mamber internal and private, since you can use it only in the abstract class and not expose it out.

Comment: The thing is I want derived classes (only from same assembly) to have access to dbContext member...How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protected internal` gives all subclasses access to the property, even when the subclass is outside the DLL. This is inconsistent with the type of the property being `internal`, because it would require a subclass from the outside to have access to the internal type.

Consider this example: I subclass `EFNLBaseRepository` from outside your DLL

```
public sealed EFNLSealedRepository : EFNLBaseRepository {
    public DoSomething() {
        // Access to dbContext should be allowed, because it is protected;
        // However, NLSubscriberDBContext should not be accessible.
        // This is an inconsistency flagged by the C# compiler.
        NLSubscriberDBContext context = dbContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got that wrong...then my question would be: How do I do dbContext member accessible only from same assembly derived classes?

Comment: @CristianGrisolia There is no way to set it like that while keeping the `EFNLBaseRepository` class public. If you need to share implementation among classes in your package, create a public interface `IEFNLBaseRepository`, make `EFNLBaseRepository` internal, make and `dbContext` protected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that another asembly can inherent the `EFNLBaseRepository` class, and that case the `internal` is making it less accessible for the derived class. Because of that conflict compiler is not allowing it.

Answer (score 0):

protected internal :
 Access is limited to the current assembly **or** types derived from the containing class.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)